# '//' operator in Python not returning correct solution

Tags: python, python-2.7, calculator, divide

I'm working on a change calculator script for my CS course.  Code is below:

```
# Set up our money variables
centValueOfTenDollarBill = 1000
centValueOfFiveDollarBill = 500
centValueOfToonie = 200
centValueOfLoonie = 100
centValueOfQuarter = 25
centValueOfDime = 10
centValueOfNickel = 5

# Set up our variables
purchaseTotal = input("Enter purchase total: ")  # Purchase costs $12.50
moneyPaid = input("Enter money paid:  ")      # Customer gives cashier $20.00

# Figure out the change
change = moneyPaid - purchaseTotal

# Echo input data to user
print("""The total of the purchase is $%0.2f.
The customer paid $%0.2f.
The cashier gives $%0.2f back to the customer in the following fashion: """ %(purchaseTotal, moneyPaid, change))

#Convert dollars into cents to facilitate the computation
purchaseTotalInCents = purchaseTotal * 100
moneyPaidInCents = moneyPaid * 100
changeInCents = change * 100

# Determine # of $10 to be given back as part of the change
numberOfTenDollarBills = changeInCents // centValueOfTenDollarBill
changeInCents = changeInCents - (centValueOfTenDollarBill * numberOfTenDollarBills)

# Determine # of $5 to be given back as part of the change
numberOfFiveDollarBills = changeInCents // centValueOfFiveDollarBill
changeInCents -= (centValueOfFiveDollarBill * numberOfFiveDollarBills)

# Determine # of $2 (toonies) to be given back as part of the change
numberOfToonieCoins = changeInCents // centValueOfToonie
changeInCents -= (centValueOfToonie * numberOfToonieCoins)

# Determine # of $1 (loonies) to be given back as part of the change
numberOfLoonieCoins = changeInCents // centValueOfLoonie
changeInCents -= (centValueOfLoonie * numberOfLoonieCoins)

# Determine # of $0.25 (quarters) to be given back as part of the change
numberOfQuarterCoins = changeInCents // centValueOfQuarter
changeInCents -= (centValueOfQuarter * numberOfQuarterCoins)

# Determine # of $0.10 (dimes) to be given back as part of the change
numberOfDimeCoins = changeInCents // centValueOfDime  #<--- PROBLEM HERE IF DIMES ARE TWO
print (numberOfDimeCoins)
changeInCents -= (centValueOfDime * numberOfDimeCoins)

# At this point, changeInCents can either be
# 5 -> 1 x $0.05 (nickels) or
# 0 -> 0 x $0.05 (nickels)
numberOfNickelCoins = changeInCents // centValueOfNickel

# Output the result: change cashier needs to give back to customer
print("\t%i x $10.00" %numberOfTenDollarBills)
print("\t%i x $ 5.00" %numberOfFiveDollarBills)
print("\t%i x $ 2.00" %numberOfToonieCoins)
print("\t%i x $ 1.00" %numberOfLoonieCoins)
print("\t%i x $ 0.25" %numberOfQuarterCoins)
print("\t%i x $ 0.10" %numberOfDimeCoins)
print("\t%i x $ 0.05" %numberOfNickelCoins)

# Indicates the end of execution
print("----\n")
```

All that's wrong (at least from what I can see) is that if the program is supposed to give back two dimes, it gives back one dime and one nickel which short changes the customer five cents.  If it's supposed to give back one dime, then there's no issue.

Example:  Say a customer paid $20 for a $13.30 item.  The change is $6.70.

```
numberOfDimeCoins = changeInCents // centValueOfDime
```

This line above should be the same as `2.0 = 20.0//10.0` but instead it's returning `1.0`.

If you paid $20 for anything where one dime is required to give back, everything is correct, like $13.20, $13.90, or $13.75 items.

Here's some example outputs below:

```
Erics-MacBook-Pro:Desktop eric$ python change.py
Enter purchase total: 13.75
Enter money paid:  20
The total of the purchase is $13.75.
The customer paid $20.00.
The cashier gives $6.25 back to the customer in the following fashion: 
    0 x $10.00
    1 x $ 5.00
    0 x $ 2.00
    1 x $ 1.00
    1 x $ 0.25
    0 x $ 0.10
    0 x $ 0.05
----

Erics-MacBook-Pro:Desktop eric$ python change.py
Enter purchase total: 12.8
Enter money paid:  20
The total of the purchase is $12.80.
The customer paid $20.00.
The cashier gives $7.20 back to the customer in the following fashion: 
    0 x $10.00
    1 x $ 5.00
    1 x $ 2.00
    0 x $ 1.00
    0 x $ 0.25
    1 x $ 0.10
    1 x $ 0.05
----
```

Is there something that I'm missing or did wrong?

Using Python 2.7.

Comment: This is just too java to be in the python section.

Comment: '//' does floor division in Python2.7, and is equal to '/'. Chances are, your value is just under 20 and you are treating it as an integer because of how floats are stored.

Comment: You must check your assumptions when something goes wrong like this. The first step, of course, is figuring out what your assumption is. In this case, it's that `changeInCents` is 20 right before the line you've identified as problematic.

Comment: Never use floats for money. Use integers to store the number of cents, and convert to dollars and cents for display only.

Comment: Don't use `input` in Python 2, either. Use `raw_input`, and parse the resulting string.

Comment: Expanding on what @chepner said...  Integers are for values that can and should be recorded precisely --- countable things like pennies or byte offsets or elements in a collection.  Floating-point numbers are for _measurements_ --- values that can (and will) be rounded, where you have to worry about details like significant figures and "plus or minus" some margin of error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you inspect the variables, you will see the problem

```
>>> changeInCents
19.999999999999886
>>> centValueOfDime
10
```

This is due to the limited precision of floating point.

You should convert the inital values to cents. eg.

```
numberspurchaseTotalInCents = int(purchaseTotal * 100)
moneyPaidInCents = int(moneyPaid * 100)
changeInCents = moneyPaidInCents - numberspurchaseTotalInCents
```

Also check out the builtin `divmod()` function

Comment: That was indeed the problem, thanks.  What I did to fix it was use the round() it to the nearest zero.  I appreciate that!

Answer (score 2):

This is because of floating point precision problem. Try this:

```
purchaseTotal = 13.3
moneyPaid = 20

change = moneyPaid - purchaseTotal
print(repr(change))  # 6.699999999999999
```

You probably expect `change` to be `0.7`, but in fact it's a number very close to `0.7`, but not precisely. In the end, `changeInCents` gets a number you expect to be `20.0`, but actually a little bit smaller.

Comment: To solve this - do all calculations as cents - and then convert back to dollar/cents.

Comment: All calculations _are_ being done in cents, @TonySuffolk66, but they're also being done in floating point.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to debug your code, but the other mates have figured it out already. You have a problem with how the numbers are stored following IEEE 754 standard (you can know more about it [here](https://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/ieee754status/IEEE754.PDF)).

My recommendation for you is to work with decimal (read [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html))

It is pretty straight forward,

```
#import and set precision
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = **x** #you decide it
a = Decimal(10)
b = Decimal(0.9)
print a-b
```

Read the documentation, it allows you to set a lot of relevant issues on how to round numbers.

Comment: Decimal is overkill here I think - especially for a student just starting off, but a good solution to the general issue.

Comment: I do agree, he seems to be just moving from javaland. But I guess it is gonna cost him less time and effort to understand this class than actually going through the whole floating point representation of numbers.